# Triangle geometry - 2 fixed points, one side changing length

Tags: geometry

Let's consider the triangle ABC, where the distances AB and AC are constant. A and C and immobile; B can move.

The triangle can have two states:

1) There is a right angle between AB and BC, B has the same x coordinate as A

```
A
| 
| 
|   
|     
B --- C
```

2) B has the same y coordinate as A, and the distance BC is double what is was before

```
B-----A
       \
        \
         \
          \
           C
```

How can I calculate the position of C, in respect to A if I know the distances AB and BC?

Comment: Isn't it trivial in the first case? I mean if you know AB. (And in that case knowing BC is unnecessary.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It belongs on MathOverflow.

Comment: AnT: the two cases are related, the distance AB and AC do not change, but B's position changes and the distance BC doubles; I need to find out how to numerically solve this and know the limits of the BC distance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: @GreenMatt Please note that this question does not belong on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/), which is for [research level math questions only](http://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Pang: Sorry, got the wrong site. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) known  |BC| = t, |A.X - C.X| = t
2) known |AB| = f, |BC| = 2*t
   unknown g = |A.Y - C.Y|

(f+t)^2 + g^2 = (2*t)^2  //grandpa Pythagoras' theorem
g = Sqrt(4*t^2 - (f+t)^2)
```